# Did Shri krishna oppose Vedas?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita

BG 2.42-43: Those with limited understanding, get attracted to the flowery words of the Vedas, which advocate ostentatious rituals for elevation to the celestial abodes, and presume no higher principle is described in them. They glorify only those portions of the Vedas that please their senses, and perform pompous ritualistic ceremonies for attaining high birth, opulence, sensual enjoyment, and elevation to the heavenly planets.

There are many verses that oppose vedas in gita.

Like

O Humans, only by performing noble and selfless deeds one should wish to live for hundred years. As you are involved in noble deeds, your mind will be purified and you will be no more attracted towards evil. This results in the increment in your knowledge, age and other good qualities. (Yajurveda 40/2)

O Agni, we adore you. Keep the sinners away from us. Take us away from path of destruction to the path of dharma so that we can enjoy through science, knowledge and wealth. (Yajurveda 40/16)

Now gita

BG 2.47: You have a right to perform your prescribed duties, but you are not entitled to the fruits of your actions. Never consider yourself to be the cause of the results of your activities, nor be attached to inaction.

BG 5.12: Offering the results of all activities to God, the karm yogis attain everlasting peace. Whereas those who, being impelled by their desires, work with a selfish motive become entangled because they are attached to the fruits of their actions.

Why it looks like bhagavad gita is opposing vedas.

Comment: He didn't oppose Vedas. Vedas has two portions , karma kanda which focuses on rituals for sense gratification and Jnana kanda which focuses on liberation. Krishna is talking about former which focuses on moving to higher realms rather than liberation.

Comment: He didn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krishna never opposed Vedas. He tries to convey the message that the information and understandings from the Vedas are used to just attain higher celestial abodes for personal selfish reasons which please one's senses by those with less understandings and never understand that all duties should be done for the happiness of the supreme lord Krishna without desire of fruits of the karma.